# Is it right to use DISTINCT and RANK() function together for distinct values in a select statement?

Tags: sql, plsql, distinct, ranking-functions

Can we use DISTINCT and RANK() function together in a select statement for distinct values? Lets take 2 scenarios
1.Using RANK() and DISTINCT
2.Using only RANK() .
In these both scenarios will we get same distinct values?

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT distinct
 col1,
 col2,
 col3,
 col4,
 row_number () over (partition by col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) RN
FROM table)
WHERE rn = 1;


SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
 col1,
 col2,
 col3,
 col4,
 row_number () over (partition by col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) RN
FROM table) 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: In the first query `ROW_NUMBER()` ensures there are no duplicate rows, so `DISTINCT` is unnecessary.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: RANK can have duplicates, so you can use DISTINCT on it (smth like: "select distinct rn from (select rank() over () rn ....  ) . While row_number gives you already distinct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windowing function (`ROW_NUMBER` here) is computed after any `GROUP BY` but *before* `DISTINCT`. Here's what an execution plan looks like for a similar SQL using a random object I selected on one of my databases:

[image]

Order of execution (read from most-indented upwards toward least-indented) is: (1) scan the table, (2) compute `ROW_NUMBER (WINDOW)`, (3) apply `DISTINCT (HASH UNIQUE)`.

This means that `DISTINCT` will not impact the result of `ROW_NUMBER` in the same query block. It *could* change the results of the outer query block if placed there, but in your case it won't because of your `rn = 1` predicate. That will select only one row per `(col1,col2)`. There's nothing left for `DISTINCT` to do, though it will have to pass through another (unnecessary) sort operation to honor the request.

Word of wisdom: avoid frequent use of `DISTINCT`. I see developers overusing it all the time. In most cases when you want to reduce granularity, `GROUP BY` is a better choice. Usually when I see `DISTINCT` in developers' code it's an attempt to hide duplicate rows caused by a many-to-many problem in their query, rather than fixing the many-to-many itself. And even if it's not hiding a problem, it is confusing to others when it's there for no purpose.